# Uploading file via PHP doesn't work on my cutsom CMS

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, content-management-system, image-upload

I had a custom made CMS website which took long time to built. The site used to work fine in shared hostings. I just moved it to VPS and for some reason the images wont upload. I checked all sorts of sollutions even canceled the first VPS account but second gave the same problem. So i believe its not about hosting.

I think there is a problem with my **process_image.php**. I think it is a similar issue to this one on [Uploading file via PHP, doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449731/uploading-file-via-php-doesnt-work). Here is the code: (I know its a very long code but any help will be appriciated. I have had 1 weeks sleepless night. Please give me some suggestions. Regards)

```
function Process_image() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    //Generate random Activation code

    function generate_code($length = 10) {
        if ($length <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $code = "";
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
        srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $code = $code . substr($chars, rand() % strlen($chars), 1);
        }
        return $code;

    }

}


function process_pic($image_path,  $type='',  $main=false, $width=175,$height=175 ) {
// $type
// 1-profile, 2-logo 3-events/news , 4-add
//
    //Get File Data Info
    $uploads = array($this->upload->data());

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    if($type=='logo') {
        return  $this->generate_logo($image_path);
    }
    else {
        //Move Files To User Folder
        foreach($uploads as $key[] => $value) {

            //Gen Random code for new file name
            $randomcode = generate_code(32);
            $newimagename = $randomcode.$value['file_ext'];

            //Creat Thumbnail
            $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
            $config['source_image'] = $value['full_path'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $config['thumb_marker'] = '_tn';
            //$config['master_dim'] = 'width';
            $config['quality'] = 75;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

            if($type=='profiles'   ) {
                $config['width'] = 100;
                $config['height'] = 100;
            }
            else if($type=='profiles' || $type=='registered_slides' ||

$type=='registered_themes'  ) {
                $config['width'] = 75;
                $config['height'] = 75;
            }

            else if($type=='favicon') {
                if($value['image_width']>32) $config['width'] = 32; else           
 $config['width'] = $value['image_width'];
                if($value['image_height']>32) $config['height'] = 32; else        
 $config['height'] = $value['image_height'];
            }
            else if($type=='logo') {
                 if($value['image_width']>250) $config['width'] = 250; else   
 $config['width'] = $value['image_width'];
                if($value['image_height']>50) $config['height'] = 50; else 
 $config['height'] = $value['image_height'];
            }
            else if($type=='bsl_ads') {
                $config['width'] = 100;
                $config['height'] = 100;
            }
            else if($type=='product_images') {
                $config['width'] = 80;
                $config['height'] = 80;
            }
            else {
                $config['width'] = $width;
                $config['height'] = $height;
            }

            $config['new_image'] =$image_path. $newimagename;


            /* Watermarking Configuration */
            $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2006 - SIMPRO';
            $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';                   // Type of watermarking.      
 Options:  text/overlay
            $config['wm_font_path'] = 'arialbd.ttf';       // TT font
            $config['wm_font_size'] = '12';
            $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'M';             // Vertical alignment:   T M   
B
            $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'C';             // Horizontal alignment: L R 
C
            $config['wm_padding'] = '20';                // Padding around text
            $config['wm_font_color'] = '#ffffff';        // Text color


            //$this->image_lib->clear();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            //$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            //$this->image_lib->watermark();

            //Move Uploaded Files with NEW Random name
            if($main) {
                rename($value['full_path'],$image_path.$newimagename);
            }
            else {
                unlink($value['full_path']);
            }



            //Make Some Variables for Database
            $imagename = $newimagename;
            $thumbnail = $randomcode.'_tn'.$value['file_ext'];
            $filesize = $value['file_size'];
            $width = $value['image_width'];
            $height = $value['image_height'];
            $timestamp = time();




            //Add Pic Info To Database
            $data = array(
                    'imagename'=>$imagename,
                    'thumbnail'=>$thumbnail,
                    'filesize'=>$filesize,
                    'width'=>$width,
                    'height'=>$height,
                    'timestamp'=>$timestamp
            );

            //Insert Info Into Database
 //
            return $data;
        }

    }
}
function generate_logo($image_path) {
    //Get File Data Info
    $uploads = array($this->upload->data());

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    //Move Files To User Folder
    foreach($uploads as $key[] => $value) {

        //Gen Random code for new file name
        $randomcode = generate_code(32);
        $newimagename = $randomcode.$value['file_ext'];

        //Creat Thumbnail
        $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
        $config['source_image'] = $value['full_path'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = false;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '_tn';
        //$config['master_dim'] = 'width';
        $config['quality'] = 75;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;


        if($value['image_width']>250) $config['width'] = 250; else $config['width'] = $value['image_width'];
        if($value['image_height']>50) $config['height'] = 50; else $config['height'] = $value['image_height'];

        $config['new_image'] =$image_path. $newimagename;

        //$this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        //$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        //Move Uploaded Files with NEW Random name
        $logo_name = $this->registered_userid.$value['file_ext'];

        $source = $image_path. $newimagename;
        $destination = $image_path.$logo_name;

        if(file_exists($destination))
          {  unlink($destination); }
        rename($source, $destination);
 //            copy($source,$destination);
        unlink($value['full_path']);

     //   die();
        //Make Some Variables for Database
        $imagename = $newimagename;
        $thumbnail = $randomcode.'_tn'.$value['file_ext'];
        $filesize = $value['file_size'];
        $width = $value['image_width'];
        $height = $value['image_height'];
        $timestamp = time();




        //Add Pic Info To Database
        $data = array(
                'imagename'=>$logo_name,
                'thumbnail'=>$logo_name,
                'filesize'=>$filesize,
                'width'=>$width,
                'height'=>$height,
                'timestamp'=>$timestamp
        );

        //Insert Info Into Database
  //
        return $data;
    }
}
function process_bannar_pic($image_path, $image_id, $thumbnail=FALSE) {

    //Connect to database
    $this->load->database();
    //Get File Data Info
    $uploads = array($this->upload->data());

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    //Move Files To User Folder
    foreach($uploads as $key[] => $value) {

        //Gen Random code for new file name
        $randomcode = generate_code(32);
        $newimagename = $randomcode.$value['file_ext'];

        //Creat Thumbnail
        if($thumbnail) {
            $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
            $config['source_image'] = $value['full_path'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $config['thumb_marker'] = '_tn';
            $config['master_dim'] = 'width';
            $config['quality'] = 75;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width'] = 175;
            $config['height'] = 175;
        }

        $config['new_image'] =$image_path. $newimagename;


        /* Watermarking Configuration */
        $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2006 - SIMPRO';
        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';                   // Type of watermarking.  Options:  text/overlay
        $config['wm_font_path'] = 'monofont.ttf';       // TT font
        $config['wm_font_size'] = '12';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'M';             // Vertical alignment:   T M B
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'C';             // Horizontal alignment: L R C
        $config['wm_padding'] = '20';                // Padding around text
        $config['wm_font_color'] = '#ffffff';        // Text color


        //$this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        //$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        //$this->image_lib->watermark();

        //Move Uploaded Files with NEW Random name
        rename($value['full_path'],$image_path.$newimagename);




        //Make Some Variables for Database
        $imagename = $newimagename;
        $thumbnail = $randomcode.'_tn'.$value['file_ext'];
        $filesize = $value['file_size'];
        $width = $value['image_width'];
        $height = $value['image_height'];
        $timestamp = time();




        //Add Pic Info To Database
        $data = array(
                'imagename'=>$imagename,
                'thumbnail'=>$thumbnail,
                'filesize'=>$filesize,
                'width'=>$width,
                'height'=>$height,
                'timestamp'=>$timestamp
        );

        //Insert Info Into Database
        $this->db->where('id', $image_id);
        $this->db->update('cms_images',$data);

    }



}



}
?>
```

Comment: Did you look in logs? What happens when you upload? Your upload destination is writable? Your code is large but hard to figure out what wrong without any logs. Hard to guess :)

Comment: I couldnt find anything on error logs. Everything looks ok when i upload. Contents "letters" for news or articles get uploaded. But images doesnt. Destination folder is 755.

Comment: Write a simple script that uses PHP's built in file functions.  Do they work?